# Citestyle and Biblatex style

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am trying to get a citestyle like this one:

> Lastname, Prof. Dr. F.; Lastname, F.; Lastname, F.; Lastname, F. : „Title
>   of Book“, Munich, 2015, 3. Edition, Publisher XY,
>   ISBN: 123-4-567-79874-4.

Closest I am able to get is this:

> Lastname, P. D. F.; Lastname, F.; Lastname, F.; Lastname, F., "Title
>   of Book", 3. Edition.; Publisher XY: Munich, 2015,
>   ISBN: 123-4-567-79874-4.

The issue lies with the order of the Location, Edition and Publisher. And also Prof. Dr. is being shortened to P. D.

I am using:

```
\usepackage[
    hyperref = true,
    isbn = true,
    backend = biber,
    style = chem-acs,
    autocite = footnote,
    sorting = none
    ]{biblatex}
```

Is it possible to get exactly the same order without using a custom bib style?

Comment: It is **extremely** uncommon to include academic degrees/titles or job descriptions in the bibliography. So you normally would not see "Prof. Dr." in the references.

Comment: @moewe I am aware of this, however, just trying to mimic the style that was given as an example by my lecturer. I think I will just ignore the academic degrees, as I've also never seen them being cited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments it is extremely uncommon to list academic degrees, titles or job descriptions in the bibliography. It would be quite tricky to get `biblatex` not to abbreviate "Prof. Dr." to "P. D." when the given name should be reduced to initials, since BibTeX and Biber will just treat the "Prof. Dr." in "Prof. Dr. Christian Drosten" as belonging to the first name. I will therefore ignore this part of the style. (It would be possibly to cook something up using the extended Biber name format, which would require a different input, or by abusing the "junior part" of the name, but neither approach seems like a good idea.)

The following is an attempt to implement the shown style with [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext)'s `ext-numeric`, which is technically speaking a custom style (which you say you don't want), but it offers some slightly advantages over doing the same with the standard style `numeric` (in the standard style we'd have to patch the drivers to stop printing the `edition` field or we'd have to delete the field and restore it later, with `biblatex-ext` we just have to redefine one bibmacro to do nothing).

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-numeric,
  sorting=none,
  giveninits=true,
  isbn=true,
  autocite=footnote,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{edition}{}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \newunit
}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,gonzalez}
ipsum \autocite{nussbaum,companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Goossens, M.; Mittelbach, F.; Samarin, A.: „The LaTeX Companion“, Reading, Mass., 1994, 1. Aufl., Addison-Wesley, 528 S.]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what has been said before, viz. that it is extremely uncommon to have academic titles given in the bibliography. However, if you really need/want to do that, since you use `biblatex` anyway, you could get the anticipated result by encoding the names in the bib-file as follows

```
author = {family=Lastname, given=Prof. Dr. F., given-i={Prof. Dr.} F and Lastname, F. and Lastname, F. and Lastname, F.}
```

Be aware that you need to do this manually for all entries, which has a large potential for errors, but it should be possible.